# combine several align-environments

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

I want to combine several `align`-environments but reset the alignment at some point.

Esp., I want to combine these:

```
\begin{align*}
& \lim(\emptyset) = \ext(\emptyset), \lim(\Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^*) = \ext(\Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^*) \text{(see above)}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
& \lim( \neg ( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* ) ) & = & \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
& & = & \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \forall n: \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
& & = & \neg \ext( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* )
\end{align*}
```

But the should not share a common alignment. (Edit: Actually, they should share the same outermost left alignment but nothing more.)

I want to combine them because it otherwise adds an empty line/space between them but I don't want that. Or is there any other way I can avoid that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you really want the first alignment in a single line, or should it be two lines? (It's 2 separate equations, after all!)

Comment: @Hendrik: Well, I could also make it two lines but that is not related to my question here. I want that the lines of the second `align` start right after. But it adds an empty line between the two `align` environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `aligned` environment inside `align*`. Note that I added a `\`  before `\lim` and before `\text` so that you get a space there. (This gives an overfull `\hbox`, but that's another thing.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\ext{ext}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \lim(\emptyset) = \ext(\emptyset),       \lim(\Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^*)
  = \ext(\Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^*)\ \text{(see above)}, \\
& \begin{aligned}
  \lim( \neg ( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* ) )
   &= \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
   &= \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \forall n: \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
   &= \neg \ext( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* )
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it aligns all of them together at the `=`. But I don't want that. I want the alignment to behave just as if it were two separates environments.

Comment: @Albert: So what do you mean when you say "they should share the same outermost left alignment"?

Comment: @Hendrik: Every line (except those which begin with `=`) should start at the same x-offset.

Comment: @Albert: Better now?

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah thanks, that is perfect. That answers also the other question. It seems that `aligned` is actually what I want there instead of `align` because `aligned` doesn't seem to center it.

Comment: @Hendrik: One further thing. I'll ask it here because I'm not sure if I really should make a separate question for it: Now the indentation is zero (relative to surrounding text). But I want it a bit indented. Would I do that also within the `align`? Or is there some `\indent` or so?

Comment: There's no indentation because the display is too wide. With the `fleqn` option of `amsmath` you'll always get the same left indentation, as I said at your other question.