# alignment in align-env: what is aligned in what way?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

In this example:

```
\begin{align*}
& \lim( \neg ( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* ) ) & = & \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
& & = & \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \forall n: \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
& & = & \neg \ext( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* )
\end{align*}
```

There is a huge space between `\lim( \neg ( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* ) )` and `=`.

Why? How can I avoid that? I actually want to have the `=` right next to it, as if I wouldn't have used `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the `align*` environment correctly: There's way too many `&`s in your code. You need only *one* `&` *before* the `=` sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\ext{ext}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\lim( \neg ( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* ) )
 &= \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
 &= \{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \forall n: \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \} \\
 &= \neg \ext( \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* )
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note that a few more things could be improved in your code: The outer parentheses of the `\lim` could be larger (use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`), and the `{|}` of the two sets could be larger, too (use `\bigl\{`, `\bigm|` and `\bigr\}`).

Comment: That looks good, except one detail: I have several other `align` environments in this parts and I want them all to start with the same left indentation. It seems that it is centered now which is not what I want.

Comment: @Albert: I'll be glad to answer [your other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13624/1235) if you provide the details I asked for. My code above is just supposed to be an answer to your question _here_, and it is, isn't it? `:-)`

Comment: The very first `&` I put there was so that the left indentation is the same as for other `align` blocks I have. In your code, it seems centered and other `align` blocks start with different left indentation. But I don't want that; I want that it always starts with the same left indentation. How?

Comment: @Albert: As I said, I answered the question you asked _here_. Let's discuss this at your other question, where it's relevant!

Comment: In my question, the indentation was actually more like what I wanted and in your answer, it is not at all anymore, that is why I haven't accepted it yet. :) It is now centered. I don't want it to be centered. Or does `align` always centers the content? How can I avoid that? And all this is I think unrelated to the other question. But maybe not. I'm not sure. I still haven't really understood how `align` works and how it does the alignment. That is why I was asking here. :) That was actually more the question than just another solution. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @Albert: Ah, now I understand what you want. Yes, it's a _feature_ of `align` to usually center its contents. If you don't want that, use `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` instead of `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble. That'll give all displayed math the same left indentation.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah perfect, that does it! :) That also answers my question in the comment on the other answer.